# how function overload when class can cast to function type

Tags: c++, overloading

Recently I am reading *c++ templates*. There is a ambiguity example in appendix B.3.4 and I add some detail to compile.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void FuncType(double, int);
void f(double, int) {  
    printf("call %s\n", __func__);
}

class IndirectFunctor {
public:
    void operator()(double, double) {  
        printf("call %s\n", __func__);
    }

    operator FuncType*() const { return &f; }
};

void activate(IndirectFunctor const& funcObj) {
    funcObj(3, 5);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    IndirectFunctor funcObj;
    activate(funcObj);
    return 0;
}
```

It says a proxy function with a implicit argument will be added to overload resolution collection when a class has a cast to function operator, thus invoking `operator FuncType*() const` needs to cast `IndirectFunctor&` to `FuncType*` which not have priority than member `operator()(double, double)`.

But the code invoke `operator FuncType*() const`, why `operator FuncType*() const` have priority than `operator()(double, double)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the call site in `activate`, `funcObj` is a const reference. Because `IndirectFunctor::operator()` is not a const member function, it is not a viable candidate for `funcObj(3, 5)`.

Either make the function call operator const (`IndriectFunctor::operator() const`) or change the parameter to `activate` to not be const (`void activate(IndirectFunctor &funcObj)`).